# Chained calls of member functions - order of calls

Tags: c++, volatile, method-chaining, operator-precedence

I have a large application containing chained function calls, like this:

```
subsystem.
    do_stuff(cfg().get("x")).
    do_stuff(cfg().get("y"));
```

Here `subsystem` is an object of a class type:

```
struct Sybsystem
{
    Sybsystem& do_stuff(int parameter)
    {
        ... // much code
        return *this; // this line makes it possible to chain calls
    }
};
```

Also, `cfg()` is a "global function" that returns a configuration object:

```
struct Configuration
{
    int get(const char* param_name);
}
Configuration& cfg();
```

The code with the chained function calls first does stuff with `x`, then with `y`; however, C++ doesn't define when the configuration parameters for `x` and `y` are extracted from the configuration object. Indeed, when i run my application in Debug and Release mode (MS Visual Studio 2005), the order of calls to `Configuration::get` is opposite.

All was well until we added support for returning random values from `Configuration::get` (for testing). When we did it, the behavior in Debug and Release mode became different.

So my question is:

Can i fix this problem and still use chained function calls? (we have much code written this way; it would be tiresome to change it all)

Can i use, for example, tricks with `volatile`?

Comment: I am slightly confused as to how results being different when you return _random values_ could ever be a problem. Surely the results should _always_ be different?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I use a pseudo-random generator with a constant seed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, and there's nothing you can do about it.

You'll have to break the chain to create your own sequence points where this order is important.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The problem in question was fixed in C++17.